# How to get all of the variables defined in a python module without imports?

Tags: python

For example, if I have the following structure:

**base.py**

```
foo = 1
bar = 2
```

**extended.py**

```
from base import *

baz = 3
qux = 4
```

I'm looking to get only the variables defined in extended.py.

---

I've tried using `dir` and 'inspect',

```
import inspect
import extended
vars = dir(extended)
members = inspect.getmembers(extended)
```

but this gives `vars = ['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux', ...]` and `members=[('bar', 2), ('baz', 3), ('foo', 1), ('qux', 4), ...]`

Is there anyway to actually do this in python, given this structure of how extended.py is defined?

Comment: If you were feeling really brave you could potentially use the [AST](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html) package to parse the module you're interested in and then pull out variable assignments from that...

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give this a bash for personal interest, it will probably work for what you want, I havent' looked at how more complex assignments work e.g. slice assignments etc:

```
import ast

with open("extended.py") as f:
    code = f.read()

tree = ast.parse(code)

assignments = [
    node
    for node in ast.walk(tree)
    if isinstance(node, ast.Assign)
]

target_variables = set()
for a in assignments:
    print("{}: {}".format(a, ast.dump(a)))
    for target in a.targets:
        target_variables.add(target.id)

print("Found {} assignments to these variable names:".format(len(assignments)))
print(target_variables)
```

Comment: This also contains assignments in function, which is probably not what he wants.

Comment: The specific example given only mentions modules doing `from x import *`, which (unlike other answers here) this doesn't show. The question says nothing about function definitions so I don't make any assumptions about the desired behaviour for them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a somewhat simple way of doing it, that is possible not perfect, but it will work:

```
def find_names_of_module(module):
    code = compile(open(module.__file__).read(), module.__name__, "exec")
    return code.co_names
```

Sadly this does also return modules imported with `from module import *` or `import module` and also functions. You could filter it to not have modules and functions if you don't want them.

If you need only the top-level variable names, here is a tweak of Tom Dalton answer that only includes top level variables:

```
def find_names_of_module(module):

    with open(module.__file__) as f:
        code = f.read()

    tree = ast.parse(code)

    assignments = (node for node in tree.body if isinstance(node, ast.Assign))
    return {target.id for a in assignments for target in a.targets}
```

Comment: Worth noting that the latter part will not find top-level variables that are defined within a conditional expression or top-level loop, even `if True: foo = 'bar'`

Comment: @TomDalton So you say it is more likely that he has variable definitions inside if statements then that he has variable declarations inside functions?

Comment: I am not saying that, nor do I claim to know which of those possibilities (if either) is true.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the structure I would go with this solution:

**base.py**

```
foo = 1
bar = 2
```

**extension.py**

```
baz = 3
qux = 4
```

**extended.py**

```
from base import *
from extension import *
```

Otherwise, I'm not sure if this code actually works and ***there must be a better way*** but you can use the difference between modules members:

```
import inspect
import base
import extended
base_members = inspect.getmembers(base)
ext_members = inspect.getmembers(extended)
ext_only_members = [member for member in ext_members if member not in base_members]
```

Since the list content is not hashable you can't use a set to get the diff.

Comment: The last method would break if you have a circular import.